# How do I make printf from right to left

Tags: c

I've written this code for converting Decimal numbers to binary but it prints the number vice versa how can I make this work?
Can I use getch command to make it happen we are currently learning getch.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(;n>0;n=n/2){
        int d = n%2;
        printf("%d", d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could write each value into an array, then print the array from its last element backwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get tricky with this by using a recursive function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_binary(int n)
{
    if (n != 0) {
        print_binary(n/2);
        printf("%d ", n%2);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    print_binary(n);
    return 0;
}
```

By printing after the recursive call returns, the digits print in the reverse order.

Each time `print_binary` is called, it calls itself with an argument of `n/2`, then prints the least significant bit.  However, each recursive call does the same thing.

Here's what the call stack looks like with `n` equal to 11 (binary 1011):

```
main
    scanf
    print_binary(11)
        print_binary(5)
            print_binary(2)
                print_binary(1)
                    print_binary(0)
                    printf("%d ", 1);
                printf("%d ", 0);
            printf("%d ", 1);
        printf("%d ", 1);
```

You can see that this results in the most significant bit being printed first.

Comment: How does this work exactly We haven't really gone into function creating...

Comment: Suggest `if (n != 0) {
        print_binary(n/2);
        printf("%d ", n%2);
    }` --> `if (n != 0) {
        print_binary(n/2); }
        printf("%d ", n%2);
    ` for `print_binary(0)`  Present code prints nothing.  Negative numbers are another issue, but likely not of interest to OP.

Comment: Thank you, Just an other question cant we use J instead of 2? Having 2 Variables for a single function?

Comment: @ArashArbabi If you wanted to print an arbitrary base, not just base 2, then yes that would work.  However, you'd need to add some extra logic to deal with outputting digits for bases greater than 10.  For example, for base 16 you would have to print `a` for 10, `b` for 11, etc.

Comment: @dbush Thanks for answering, But how do I make a Function that accepts two variables?

Comment: @dbush I actually found out what was wrong, I kept getting too few arguments error, I realized I didn't input j the second time. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way, working from most significant bit, with "zero supression". No reversal is needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = 0;                              // the value
    int hadone = 0;                         // 0 suppression control
    int bits = 8 * sizeof n;                // assume 8 bits for example
    unsigned mask = 1u << (bits-1);         // set msb of mask

    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(mask) {
        if(n & mask) {                      // is it a 1 bit?
            putchar('1');
            hadone = 1;                     // cancel 0 suppression
        }
        else if(hadone || mask == 1) {      // ensure a lone `0` goes out
            putchar('0');
        }
        mask >>= 1;                         // next bit
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
42
101010
```

Comment: No need for special  "ensure a lone `0` goes out" if loop was a `do { ...} while (mask);`

Comment: @chux I tried the `do { } while;` and removed the `mask == 1` test, but no output for `0`. I remember you have corrected me on this before, but this time the loop tests the mask, not the value.

Comment: Fair enough, UV

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-recursive solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n;
    char buf[100];
    char *bp;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &n);

    bp = buf;

    // store into array instead of printing [chars will be reversed]
    // NOTE: we use "bp == buf" to force output if entered number is zero
    for (; n>0 || bp == buf; n=n/2){
        int d = n%2;
        bp += sprintf(bp, "%d", d);
    }

    // print array in reverse order
    for (bp -= 1; bp >= buf;  --bp)
        fputc(*bp,stdout);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store digits into an array , and reverse it , to get the correct number .